# Compile time range check in std::array

Tags: c++, g++, stdarray

I would like to perform range check for a std::array at compile time. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void rarelyUsedFunction(const std::array<double, 2>& input)
{
    std::cout << input[5] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<double, 2> testArray;
    rarelyUsedFunction(testArray);
}
```

If I compile this with g++ there is no warning or error, despite the undefined access to an element which is not in the array. The compiled program just prints some random value.

Is there a compiler option in g++ for a suitable range/boundary check, that is performed during compile time? I know that I can add "-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG" but this will only perform a check during runtime. If I have a function which is not called very often, this won't be triggered.

I am aware, that such a range check could not be performed in all circumstances, but in the case above, the compiler should be able to spot the problem!?

Comment: I believe this is the purpose of `std::get` being overloaded for arrays

Comment: in principle the compiler could spot the problem, but consider that `std::array` is just a custom type like others, and the parameter you pass is generally not a compile time constant

Comment: A compiler warning on this is something I consider to be only a matter of time.

Comment: @user4581301 A compiler warning may not always be good enough here as it relies on the compiler inferring that the value is determinable at compile time. Sure for a literal this is trivial, but that's not always the case, and the index not being marked as `constexpr` would not be indicated in any way. The compile-time check could silently be removed from the program, so a way to explicitly request compile-time bounds-checking is still useful.

Comment: The question is "Is doing it worth the effort?" Sooner or later some one will write the check, that's inevitable because people are just "like that". Whether the check makes it into the compiler or not depends on what impact it has on the compiler's speed and complexity.

Comment: And since warnings are non-binding, you still get a program, anyone who really wants this behaviour will want the error version, even if they have to call something to get it.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, [`std::get(std::array)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) will do that nicely for you, since it is obligated to do such bounds checking:

> I must be an integer value in range [0, N). This is enforced at compile time as opposed to at() or operator[].

In your example, it would look like this:

```
void rarelyUsedFunction(const std::array<double, 2>& input)
{
    std::cout << std::get<5>(input) << std::endl; // <---- Compilation error!
}
```

If the index is not just a literal, you can still calculate it with "complex" code as long as you manage to stuff it in a `constexpr` variable:

```
void rarelyUsedFunction(const std::array<double, 2>& input)
{
    constexpr std::size_t index = /* Whatever, as long as it compiles... */;
   
    std::cout << std::get<index>(input) << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously, in either case, this involves providing the compiler with a **hard** guarantee that the index is known at compile time.

Comment: i am still learning new stuff about c++11 =)

Comment: As a sidenote regarding having to know the exact index at compile time: It would be possible to finagle something a little looser with the use of dependant types, but that can become very complicated very fast.

Comment: ADL for function templates is a C++20 feature.

Comment: Can just use `std::get`, no ADL is necessary.

Comment: @evg, @HolyBlackCat Fair enough, ADL-using `std`  functions whenever possible is a personal preference of mine that has no bearing on OP's question. I removed it.